# 50s movie with a creature that looked like a Christmas tree made of garbage bags

Tags: story-identification, movie

My husband is trying to recall the name of a 50s sci-fi movie that had a creature that looked like a Christmas tree made of garbage bags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a long shot, but any chance they're thinking of [*The Creeping Terror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Creeping_Terror)? It's from 1964, so not exactly the 50s, but the monster does look pretty awful and from some angles "Christmas tree made of garbage bags" fits.

[image: The monster]

(Image is from a review on [Monsters A-Go-Go](http://monstersagogo.com/the-creeping-terror))

Whole movie is on YouTube, at [around 40 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5twP_19CEA&t=40m12s) you get a good look at the monster.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Leona : glad to see you got the answer you were looking for. Please can you mark E Z Hart's answer as correct

Comment: I remember MST3K's treatment of this. You could see one of the the monster's victims climb into its mouth.

Comment: I'm new to this website - someone asked me to mark E Z Hart's answer as correct.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a stretch, but maybe "It Conquered the World"? The monster is sometimes described as looking like a giant cucumber, but its outline is conical.

[Here's a still.](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FM%2FMV5BNTFjMTAxNmEtNDVlNS00ZjQ3LTk3NWEtZmQ0NjQ0NGMzN2EyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTE2NzA0Ng%40%40._V1_.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt0049370%2Fmediaviewer%2Frm267734016&docid=8Sz_t_6JsIpBmM&tbnid=8xZyjJvEVGBPPM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwihqLWqlaTmAhUkheAKHYFmAS0QMwhVKAQwBA..i&w=720&h=540&bih=741&biw=1536&q=it%20conquered%20the%20world&ved=0ahUKEwihqLWqlaTmAhUkheAKHYFmAS0QMwhVKAQwBA&iact=mrc&uact=8)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Very close, but that's not the one. My husband has this movie.  He says the creature is covered with what looked like layers of garbage bags.

Comment: Don’t you mean “its outline is comical?” Because I feel that word fits better.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod It can be both things!